# Difference between addItem and insertItemAt method in java

Tags: java

What is the Difference Between addItem and inserItemAt method in java?

One thing that i have noticed while making a program is that **addItem** method starts putting
entries in the last in JComboBox. 
**insertItemAt** method pins the entry at specific position.

*Is That The Only Difference? *

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the implementation of the underlying datamodel but as for the semantics, yes that would be the only difference. Here are some differences for `insertItemAt`:
 - might throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException if the specified index is invalid 
 - does not select an item whereas `addItem` selects the inserted item if it is the only one in the list

Different implementation might do things differently and have different performance, e.g. a linked list might be faster for `insertItemAt` than an array based list.

Answer (score 0):

> Is That The Only Difference?

From the standpoint of how it affects the underlying Collection, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Both insert items, the only diference is: the first insert the item in the end like a stack, and the second one inserts an item in an indicated position, obviously moving the items according to.

So basically, yes, that's the only differece